# Why is second class not assigned to input element

Tags: html, css, sass

I have designed an input button in SCSS

```
.editButton /* button in edit window */
{
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 12px;

    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    padding: 2px 5px 2px 5px;

    border: 0.1em solid var(--edit-button-border-color);

    color: var(--edit-button-text-color);
    background: var(--edit-button-bg-color);
    border-radius: 4px;

    .fullWidth
    {
        width: 100% !important;
    }
}
```

which is leading into css file

```
.editButton {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 12px;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  padding: 2px 5px 2px 5px;
  border: 0.1em solid var(--edit-button-border-color);
  color: var(--edit-button-text-color);
  background: var(--edit-button-bg-color);
  border-radius: 4px;
}
.editButton .fullWidth {
  width: 100% !important;
}
```

My HTML

```
<input type = "button" id = "pmLettersEditFilterSend" class = "editButton fullWidth" value = "...">
```

But the fullWidth is not assigned to the element. Webdevelopers output:

```
<input type="button" id="pmLettersEditFilterSend" class="editButton fullWidth" value="Create Letter">
```

and the Filter styles:

```
element {
}
.editButton {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 12px;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    padding: 2px 5px 2px 5px;
    border: 0.1em solid var(--edit-button-border-color);
    color: var(--edit-button-text-color);
    background: var(--edit-button-bg-color);
    border-radius: 4px;
}
.pmLettersFilterFilterTitleDiv {
    text-align: left;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: var(--filter-accordeon-button-text-color);
}
#pmLettersEditTemplateDiv {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you are actually selecting a child element instead of the same element in your scss. It should be:

```
.editButton /* button in edit window */
{
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 12px;

    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    padding: 2px 5px 2px 5px;

    border: 0.1em solid var(--edit-button-border-color);

    color: var(--edit-button-text-color);
    background: var(--edit-button-bg-color);
    border-radius: 4px;

    &.fullWidth
    {
        width: 100% !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ahhh thx, sometimes you look on something for hours and don't see the problem